# C++ Cereal XML-Archive not working with stringstream

Tags: c++, serialization, stringstream, cereal

I am trying to get cereal-serialization to work. But somehow it does not work with the **XML-Archive** in combination with a **stringstream**.

Here is my example:

```
std::stringstream ss;

cereal::XMLOutputArchive oarchive(ss);
oarchive(cereal::make_nvp("data", mydata));

ss.str(); //empty
```

The wierd thing is, that the **JSON-Archive** is working totally fine, and if a put the **std::cout** into the XML-Archive, it prints out my serialization. Only the stringstream stays empty.

I tried to find a solution in the [documentation](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/) but did not find anything about it. Did someone else have a similar problem?

*Thanks in advance!*

Comment: From the [documentation](https://uscilab.github.io/cereal/quickstart.html#serialize-your-data): `"Archives are designed to be used in an RAII manner and are guaranteed to flush their contents only on destruction ..."`.  So try scoping `oarchive` such that its destructor is invoked *before* the `ss.str()` call.

Comment: Well, next time, I'll put on my glasses. That worked! Thank you!